# Is there a "continue" in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I've recently started learning Haskell and currently trying to writing basic Haskell functions.

I've written a function called `intToRoman` which should convert Integer number to Roman number. It divides the number in list of integers ( 1400 ->[1,4,0,0])  and converts every number into the Roman number taking into the account length of list to determine whenever is a thousand or hundred.

However, it doesn't stop and checks zeros as well. For instance, number 1400 will return:

```
 MCD** Exception: Map.!: given key is not an element in the map
 CallStack (from HasCallStack)
```

Here is the code itself:

```
mapInttoRoman:: M.Map Int String
mapInttoRoman = M.fromList
          [(1,"I"),(4,"IV"),(5,"V"),(9,"IX"),(10,"X"),(40,"XL")
          ,(50,"L"),(100,"C"),(400,"CD"),(900,"CM"),(500,"D"),(1000,"M")]

listOfInt :: Int -> [Int]
listOfInt 0 = [ ]
listOfInt c = listOfInt(c`div`10) ++ [c`mod`10]

duplicate :: String -> Int -> String
duplicate string n = concat $ replicate n string

intToRoman :: Int -> String
intToRoman 0 = ""
intToRoman c = createInt x (len-1)
 where x = listOfInt c
       len = length x
       createInt y xz = findRoman (head y) xz ++ createInt(drop 1 y)(xz-1)
        where findRoman b l
               | l < 1      = mapInttoRoman M.! b
               | b == 0     = " "
               | l == 3     = duplicate (mapInttoRoman M.! (10^l)) b
               | b == 1     = mapInttoRoman M.! (10^l)
               | otherwise  = mapInttoRoman M.! (b*10^l)
```

Comment: Your `| b == 0 = " "` case fails to catch this because the `| l < 1 = ..` case is checked first. You can switch their order. (It'll then fail because you try to get the head of an empty list, so you'll have to add a base case for `createInt [] _ = ""`)

Comment: I understand that you may be new to Haskell, but please consider reading the [style guide](https://github.com/tibbe/haskell-style-guide/blob/master/haskell-style.md). This is not good code.

Comment: @AJFarmar I don't think that is the right thing at all to worry about when you're learning a new language with lots of new concepts and writing programs just for your own education. A style guide matters for programs that need to be maintained.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Algorithm you use is not correct, and you made it more complicated than it needs to be.

Also the list was not complete, I added 90 and 900 cases.

Have a look at this code .. I think it's very simple and you will get it easily.

```haskell
import qualified Data.Map as M

    mapInttoRoman:: M.Map Int String
    mapInttoRoman = M.fromList
              [(1,"I"),(4,"IV"),(5,"V"),(9,"IX"),(10,"X"),(40,"XL")
              ,(50,"L"),(90,"XC"),(100,"C"),(400,"CD"),(500,"D"),(900,"CM"),(1000,"M")]

    intToRoman :: Int -> String
    intToRoman 0 = ""
    intToRoman n | M.member n mapInttoRoman = mapInttoRoman M.! n
                 | otherwise = val ++ intToRoman (n-key) 
                 where
                    keys = reverse (M.keys mapInttoRoman)
                    key  = maxValidKey n keys
                    val  = mapInttoRoman M.! key
                    maxValidKey n (k:ks) 
                      | n >= k = k
                      | otherwise = maxValidKey n ks
```

Tests :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Explanation inline.

```
import qualified Data.List as L

{-
1. Find the floor of 'n' in the mapping, i.e. the highest
   decimal value 'v' that is less than or equal to 'n'.
2. Add the corresponding string to the answer, and subtract
   'v' from 'n'.
3. Repeat until n = 0.

<$> from Functor, fmap
(<$>) :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

<> from Monoid, mappend
(<>) :: Monoid m => m -> m -> m

>>= from Monad, bind
(>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
-}
numerals :: Integer -> Maybe String
numerals n
  | n > 3000 || n <= 0 = Nothing
  | otherwise = (snd <$> x) <> (x >>= (\y -> numerals (n - fst y)))
  where
    x = L.find (\(i, _) -> i <= n) xs
    xs =
      [ (1000, "M"),
        (900, "CM"),
        (500, "D"),
        (400, "CD"),
        (100, "C"),
        (90, "XC"),
        (50, "L"),
        (40, "XL"),
        (10, "X"),
        (9, "IX"),
        (5, "V"),
        (4, "IV"),
        (1, "I")
      ]
```